# Rails Spree shipping.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

How I can combined this two shipping into a single without double price for shipping. Thnks [image]

Comment: Seems like you added the product twice in the cart

Comment: no, just one click (((

Comment: this is default install spree

Comment: Nope, that's not default working on spree for last couple of years

Comment: This is probably done due to backorderable splitter. Please confirm if the quantity of product is 10 and its marked as backorderable ?